# Power BI embed report with test and live DataSource as parameters

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We have Power BI reports with datasources based on parameters (test and live).  Now that these reports are embedded we would like to choose the live or test datasource by passing a parameter to the API.

Is this possible with parameters or filters?

These reports have access to the database, not a predefined data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Parameters are per report, i.e. all users looking at the report will see the same parameter values (same test or live environment). Filters on the other hand can be set differently for each user, but this will not work for your case. To make it work, your report must connect to both environments, for each table load all rows from both of them, and then the filter will filter out one of them. This is inconvenient and inefficient. Just deploy the report twice in two different workspaces (one for test and one for live) and change which one to embed. You may also want to take a look at [Deployment pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-overview).